# Convert UNC Path to NTFS local path

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a problem converting UNC location to local drive in powershell. So my code basically takes input from user as read Host as UNC path for a DB Backup location. The location could be like this `\\ServerName\m$\SQLBackups\123`.

It then prompts where the backup is being copied from. Again this is a UNC path such as `\\ServerName\g$\SQLRestores\444\Filename.bak`.

I need to convert both paths to their local path so that it reads `m:\sqldbackups\123` and `g:\sqlrestores\444\Filename.bak`.

Here is my code below and I have added a comment of what I want the final output to be.

```
$BackupPath = "\\ServerName\m$\SQLBackups\123"
$Dumps = Split-Path -Path $BackupPath -Leaf
$Drive = Split-Path -Path $BackupPath -Parent
$LastTwo = $Drive.Substring($Drive.get_Length()-2)


$FullNTFS = $LastTwo + "\" + $Dumps
$FullNTFS = $FullNTFS.Replace("$",":")
$FullNTFS 
#This should be M:\SQLBACKUPS\123

$RestorePath = "\\ServerName\g$\SQLRestores\444\Filename.bak"
$Dumps = Split-Path -Path $RestorePath -Leaf
$Drive = Split-Path -Path $RestorePath -Parent
$LastTwo = $Drive.Substring($Drive.get_Length()-2)


$FullNTFS = $LastTwo + "\" + $Dumps
$FullNTFS = $FullNTFS.Replace("$",":")
$FullNTFS 
#This should be read as g:\sqlrestores\444\FileName.bak
```

Answer (score 8):

`Split-Path` won't work unless the path is to a directory or file at the root of the share.

Use [`Path.GetPathRoot()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getpathroot(v=vs.110).aspx) instead to get the host and share name:

```
$Drive = [System.IO.Path]::GetPathRoot($BackupPath)
$Dumps = $BackupPath.Substring($Drive.Length)
$Drive = $Drive.Substring($Drive.LastIndexOf('\') + 1).Replace('$',':')
$NTFSPath = "$Drive$Dumps"
```

Comment: That's a really nice way to do it! I'd also add `ToUpper()` to the drive letter, but that's just vanity :)

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Thank you. To get the file name i have done $FileName = Split-Path $BackupPath -leaf

Answer (score 1):

```
# -replace operator with regex does the trick
PS C:\> '\\ServerName\m$\SQLBackups\123' -replace '(?:.+)\\([a-z])\$\\','$1:\'
m:\SQLBackups\123
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer above is the correct way to do it, but still, sometimes simple pattern matching might be enough:

```
"\\server2.net\g$\foo\bar\baz", "\\server1.com\c$\baz\bar\foo" |
Select-String -Pattern "([A-z])\`$(.*)" |
%{ "$($_.Matches.Groups[1].value):$($_.Matches.Groups[2].value)" }
```