# Get ShareName from UNC Path

Tags: powershell

I'm on a task where I need to get the local path on a server from a UNC Path.

Basically `\\server\MyShare\Somewhere\Bla` should be e.g `D:\foo\bar\somewhere\bla`

I know the Server Host from `[system.Uri]$Path` so I know in which server to look for the local path

I can use `Get-SmbShare` to get the shares on the server.

The only thing I need to compare the two now, is to split the UNC Path and get the Sharename.

Is there an easy way to do so? `-split '\'` does not work.

I'd love to have an array in the end where I could just pick `[1]`. Any other methods are also more than welcome.

Comment: `("\\server\MyShare\Somewhere\Bla" -split '\\')[3]` returns `MyShare` The split operator is RegEx based, so you need to escape the backslash with another one.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901884/convert-unc-path-to-ntfs-local-path) answer. If it is relevant!

Comment: thanks a lot to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

For a `$list` of values of type  `[System.URI]` type You can:

```
   $result=@()
    Foreach ($uri in $list)
    {
    $object =""|select URI,Hostname,Localpath 
        $object.uri=$uri.LocalPath
        $object.hostname=$uri.Authority
        $object.LocalPath= Invoke-Command -ComputerName $($uri.Authority) -ScriptBlock {param ($uri) (Get-SmbShare ($uri.AbsolutePath -split '/')[1]).path} -ArgumentList $uri
    $result+=$object
    }
$result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the unc path like this:

```
$uncPath = '\\server\MyShare\Somewhere\Bla'
$server, $share, $remainingPath = ($uncPath -replace '^\\+', '').Split("\", 3)
```

Then, using WMI to get the local path for the share:

```
$localShare = Get-WmiObject win32_share -ComputerName $server | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $share} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
```

or use the Get-SmbShare cmdlet:

```
$localShare = Get-SmbShare -Name $server | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $share} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
```

Combine this $localShare with the $remainingPath you got earlier from the split and you'll get the full local path

```
$localPath = Join-Path $localShare $remainingPath
```